# Coded UI Test Builder with VS2013 crashing IE10/11

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

Our team was having some memory leak issues with VS2012, so recently upgraded to VS2013 ultimate.

We use Coded UI to run test automation.

However, since updating, when we use the Coded UI Test Builder, as soon as we use the tool to inspect elements in IE and hover over the browser, IE crashes.

This happens on multiple peoples' machines, and with both IE10 and IE11.

I've tried on my machine with IE10 and IE11, and with both, as soon as I mouse-over with the tool, it crashes (IE crashes).

Anyone seen any solution or fixes for this?

Comment: "It crashes" is a very poor description of the problem. What diagnostics are generated? Have you looked in all the usual places? What IE plugins are installed? Have you tried attaching a debugger to IE before it crashes? What have you tried to identify the problem?

Comment: @AdrianHHH I've tried debugging from the 'IE has crashed' window without success, the debugger doesn't seem to accept the process at that point. It's even locked up the whole PC when doing so.  I've tried switching in and out of compatibility mode, as this helped with one colleague.  I've shown that it seems more likely to crash when the window being inspected is a secondary / pop up window, but that may just be anecdotal.  No plugins are installed. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both IE10 and IE11 to see if that helps. Sadly, no.

Comment: Happy to go digging for any information that you think may help, but at present, that's all I could think of.

Comment: Event logs? Web search for terms such as "how to analyze internet explorer crash".

Comment: Event logs aren't enabled by default for IE, and we don't have admin rights to add the key to the registry.  This is why my focus of investigation has been from the Coded UI angle, rather than the IE angle.  Especially given it was fine until we upgraded to VS2013.